# Cycling CSS3 animation with a pause period?

Tags: css, keyframe, css-animations

I want to run an animation after a pause in a cycle. For [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rDKGN/),

```
@-webkit-keyframes test {
    0%  { opacity:0; }
    50% { opacity:1; }
    100%{ opacity:0;}
}
.test {
    -webkit-animation:test 5s linear 10s infinite forwards;
}
```

I want to pause/delay the animation for `10s`, then doing the animation for `5s` and repeating this cycles.

The above example, only works for the first cycle. How can I induce delay/pause in each cycle for infinite cycling? In other words, I need a `15s` cycle but with `5s` of animation of FULL `keyframe` (from 0% to 100%).

NOTE that I do not aim to change the `keyframe` percentages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without javascript what you desire is impossible without changing your current keyframes. You could do the following instead, but that is the only non-javascript fix for a delay each time

```
@-webkit-keyframes test {
    0%     { opacity: 0; }
    16.66% { opacity: 1; }
    33.33% { opacity: 0; }
    100%   { opacity: 0; }
}
.test {
    -webkit-animation:test 15s linear infinite forwards;
}
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rDKGN/1/)

The only other way, like mentioned before, is to use javascript to reset the CSS animation. [Helpful article on that here](http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)