# Make a pause during infinite CSS3 animation

Tags: css, animation

I try to make an animation that run every 3 seconds **without JavaScript**. My animation's duration is 1 second.

I'm only able to wait 3seconds the first occurence then it's a loop of 1s animation.

My code so far: https://jsfiddle.net/belut/aojp8ozn/32/

```
.face.back {
    -webkit-animation: BackRotate 1s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    animation: BackRotate 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}

.face.front {
    -webkit-animation: Rotate 1s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    animation: Rotate 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}


@-webkit-keyframes Rotate {
    from {-webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes BackRotate {
    from {-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform:rotateY(540deg);}
} 
@keyframes Rotate {
    from {-webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);}
}
@keyframes BackRotate {
    from {-webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);}
}
```

I know how to do it with javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/belut/fk3f47jL/1/

I tried this answer without success: [Cycling CSS3 animation with a pause period?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054870/cycling-css3-animation-with-a-pause-period)

Can you help me please?

**EDIT**
Thanks great answers i'm also able to make this scenario:
wait 2s, run 1s flip, wait 2s, run 1s back_flip, wait 2s.

```
#f1_container {
      position: relative;
      margin: 10px auto;
      width: 90px;
      height: 90px;
      z-index: 1;
}
#f1_container {
      perspective: 1000;
}
#f1_card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
img {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
}

.face {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      backface-visibility: hidden; 
}
.face.back {
      display: block;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.face.back {
    -webkit-animation: BackRotate 5s linear infinite;
}

.face.front {
    -webkit-animation: Rotate 5s linear infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes Rotate {
    0%,40% {-webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);}
    50%,90% {-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes BackRotate {
    0%,40% {-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);}
    50%,90% {-webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform:rotateY(540deg);}
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like the only way to achieve this is to extend the animation so that it lasts `4s` instead of `1s`. Then you could delay the animation by animating from `75%` to `100%` (rather than `0%` to `100%`).

In doing so, there is essentially an artificial delay in the animation itself. You just have to do the math to figure out how long this delay is in correlation with the total length of the animation itself.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/kds0dy8f/)

```
.face.back {
      display: block;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.face.back {
    -webkit-animation: BackRotate 4s linear infinite;
    animation: BackRotate 4s linear infinite;
}

.face.front {
    -webkit-animation: Rotate 4s linear infinite;
    animation: Rotate 4s linear infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes Rotate {
    75% {-webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes BackRotate {
    75% {-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform:rotateY(540deg);}
} 
@keyframes Rotate {
    75% {-webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);}
}
@keyframes BackRotate {
    75% {-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform:rotateY(540deg);}
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I'd already commented and was building the demo. :) - https://jsfiddle.net/aojp8ozn/36/

Comment: @Paulie_D Ah, sorry about that. I saw your comment after I submitted this. Wish I could give you an upvote

Comment: No problem You have the answer. I'm not that desperate for the rep :>

Comment: Thanks Josh,
Easy enough to be understandable :)

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure exactly when it was released, and it's not the most cross-browser approach (does not cover older browsers like I.E. 9) but you could use the `animationPlayState` style prop. Theres some documentation on this [found here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-play-state.asp) if you want to check it out.

```
animationPlayState=false
webkitAnimationPlayState=false

function pause() {
    var animationElement = document.getElementById('animatedItem');
    animationElement.style.animationPlayState='paused';
    animationElement.style.webkitAnimationPlayState='paused';
}
```

As you can see this put's the items animation into a `"paused"`state, to put it back where it left the animation off at, you can set it to the `"running"` state that this prop accepts.

[Here is a quick example](http://www.tutorialspark.com/css3/CSS3_Animation_Pause_Resume_Demo.php) I found when browsing Google.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do this, as @Josh mentioned, by extending the animation. For example, if you want your animation to last 0.5 seconds with a 3 second pause, you make the entire animation 3.5 seconds, and then use percentages to extend it. (0.5 seconds is about 14% of 3.5 seconds.)

In the code below, I created a DIV with transparent gradient that is the same width as the parent, and then animated it from left to right to give a shimmer effect.

```
.shimmer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;

    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.85) 60%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(25%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(60%,rgba(255,255,255,0.85)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,0.85) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,0.85) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,0.85) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background-image: linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,0.85) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: 30% 100%;
    left: -100%;

    z-index: 101;

    animation-name: shine;
    animation-duration: 3.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes shine {
    0% { left: -100%; }
    14% { left: 100%; }
    100% { left: 100%; }
}
```

From 14% to 100%, the DIV doesn't move, but the animation continues for additional time, giving the effect of a pause.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ending state in the animation which will play like a delay. Check the example below, simple animation that runs for 4 sec but the last 3 sec is delayed.

```css
body {
  perspective: 500px;
}

/* clear background */
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 0;
}

/* crops animations that exceeds one line area */
.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

/* flipping class and key frames*/
.flipX {
  animation: 4s anim-flipX ease infinite;
}
@keyframes anim-flipX {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateX(9def);
  }
  
  20% {
    /* animate nothing to pause animation at the end */
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
  60% {
    /* animate nothing to pause animation at the end */
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
   100% {
    /* animate nothing to pause animation at the end */
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='line'>
    <h2 class='flipX'>flip vertical</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```